# How to add field in inherited notebook/page/field

Tags: python, odoo

I have inherited 'account.bank.statement' module.
I need to add an extra field inside 'Transactions' tab.

## file.py

```
class account_bank_statement(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.bank.statement'
     extra_info = fields.Char(string="Extra info")
```

## file.xml

```
<record id="view_bank_statement_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">account.bank.statement.form</field>
            <field name="model">account.bank.statement</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_bank_statement_form"/>
            <field name="mode">extension</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
               <xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page[1]/field[@name='line_ids']/tree/field[@name='date']" position="after">
                   <field name="extra_info"/>
               </xpath>
             </field>
    </record>
```

But , I got this error :

```
"ValueError: Field `extra_info` does not exist

Error context:
View `account.bank.statement.form`
[view_id: 1043, xml_id: bank_statement_upload.view_bank_statement_form, model: account.bank.statement, parent_id: 639]
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

in file.py

```
class account_bank_statement_line(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.bank.statement.line'
     extra_info = fields.Char(string="Extra info")
```

Because you are adding info field in line_ids

Answer (score 1):

Please be informed that you need to add an extra field in transaction tab, which is **`account.bank.statement.line`** model.

So please try to **inherit** **`account.bank.statement.line`** model instead of account.bank.statement. This will rectify your error.

Answer (score 1):

Added dependency in **'depends' : ['account']** in manifest file. And change your mode to **_inherit = 'account.bank.statement.line'**

And you reduce your XPath like,

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='line_ids']//field[@name='date']" position="after">
    <field name="extra_info"/>
<xpath>
```

Update your app.

Thanks